TypeError: crypto is not a function in create-react-app hello world
I'm fairly new to react (webdev in general), and built a simple hello world using npx create-react-app.
However when running it (both with a simple npm start, or building and using serve) I'm getting the following error when loading the page using my local address (ie: 192.168.1.2), rather than localhost or 127.0.0.1
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: crypto[_0xfb7f08(...)] is not a function
    at action ((index):1:11288)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at (index):1:11164
    at _0x2f754d ((index):1:11647)
    at Object.get ((index):1:12733)
    at (index):1:46867
    at _0x1daff0 ((index):1:47019)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1:47823)

followed shortly by
Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

I've tried googling the problem, but don't know enough to properly search for a solution and at this point I'm at a loss for what else to try. It feels like either something thats really obvious and I've just overlooked it, or something was deprecated and this now no longer works properly.
Even if the solution is simply "Use X instead," I'd like to understand where this error is coming from.
Here's the dependencies for  the project:

  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

index.js:
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

App.js

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


What is the specific code that's causing the error? What debugging have you done so far?

I can't tell! The trace seems to point to the  </html>  closing tag in index.html. If there's a better way for me to debug and get more specific info please point me to it! I'm fairly new to JS / React.
As far as I'm aware, there is no crypto used in the project.

I had that once, I believe the issue was somehow related to window.crypto (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) and the crypto library included in node. I wanted to use the window.crypto, but somehow I got the nodeJS crypto Library, which either has a different signature or doesn't work in browsers. Check your files, if you're using crypto anywhere, or if it comes from a library, make sure your dependencies are correct (as start as little as possible, check with some tutorials).

Nothing I can find seems to use window.crypto - unless it's buried somewhere I don't realize. I've added the my App.js and index.js to the OP as well, in case there's something in there I missed.

Does it only happen when you don't use localhost / 127.0.0.1? Check your network tab, are there some things that fail loading? Maybe something tries to load from 127.0.0.1 still, that would lead to a CORS failure probably.
